# What happens if ntohl() is called with an integer that is already in host byte order?

Tags: c, endianness

If I use ntohl() on an integer which is already in host byte order will that cause any problems?

If not, how does the ntohl() function know its argument is already in host byte order?

Comment: what happens if you multiply a number by -1, twice?

Comment: @hexa: There's no requirement that `ntohl` be order-2. If host endianness is weirder, it might make a mess.

Comment: @R.. it has to be really weird. do you know of such a platform/arch?

Comment: No, and I doubt any exist, but it's still not a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't make any sense. For `ntohl` nothing is high-order or low-order.

- If the endianness of the system is the same as network order, it will do nothing
- Otherwise it will swap stuff around

Comment: yeah thats what i meant to ask  thanks:)
sorry for sttupid question .

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't know. It assumes it's given an integer in network byte order and converts it to host, if necessary - that is all.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking "If I call ntohl() on an integer twice, will it cause a problem?"

The answer is "Yes."

This should be obvious if you think about the name of the function. It is named "Network to Host Long". After calling this function the integer is now in host byte order not in network byte order.

Comment: Of course, host byte order may be the same as network byte order, in which case...

Comment: @Roddy: In which case there's no need to call the function at all. Except that the code wouldn't be portable anymore.